# For loop not reaching end for a specfic testcase, LeetCode problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

My code does not work for this leetcode problem [Dota 2 Senate](https://leetcode.com/problems/dota2-senate/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=leetcode-75),specifically, it does not work for this testcase: "DRRD", here is the stdout that my debugging printlines gave for this input:

```
['D', 'R', 'R', 'D']
R
['D', 'R', 'D']
final for this cycle ['R', 'D']
R
['R', 'D']
final for this cycle ['R']
last dog r
```

Output
"Radiant"
Expected
"Dire"

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def predictPartyVictory(self, senate: str) -> str:
        '''We have the list of the string, have a loop that  get the first element 
        and if it's R it removes the next D and vice versa, if there isn't try/ except a value error to win.'''
        senateList= list(senate)
        
        def votingRound(senators: list):
            
            if len(senators) == 1:
                if senators[0] == "R":
                    print(f'last dog r')
                    return "Radiant"
                else:
                    print(f'last dog d')
                    return "Dire"

            for senator in senators:
                print(senator)
                print(senators)
                if senator == "R":
                    try:
                        senators.remove("D")
                    except:
                        print(f'only r')
                        return "Radiant"
                else:
                    try:
                        senators.remove("R")
                    except:
                        print(f'only d')
                        return "Dire"
            
            print(f'final for this cycle {senators}')
            return votingRound(senators)


        return votingRound(senateList)
```

I am not sure why the loop does not execute for the last D in the initial senators list, when for other testcases the code works perfectly.

The class is being called by the autograder, where it calls the predictPartyVictory() with the string for that testcase.

Comment: Welcome! Do not remove values while iterating. It will give unexpected results.

Comment: You should add also how you are using the class so we can try your code. In any case @Goku-standswithPalestine is right, when you remove an element of a list the code can skip an iteration or have some other strange behaviours.

Comment: How would I rewrite the code to not change while iterating? using .copy() in the for loop exceeds stack size in some testcases.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is that your code iterates a list while also removing items from that list. If for instance the iteration is at index 3 and you remove the item at index 0, then the next iteration will still be at index 4, but that is not the next item... The next item is now at index 3 (after the removal at index 0). And so your loop skips elements.

Another issue concerns your strategy to remove the senator (from the opposing party) that comes first *starting at the left side* of the list. That is not an optimal strategy. You should remove the opposition senator that would be the first one *getting their turn* in the next rounds. That might not be the one you removed. It might be a senator at an index *after* the current index.

#### Circular Linked List

There are many ways to approach this. We should also consider that removing from a standard list is not very efficient: all subsequent entries need to shift one position back. You could for instance work with a circular linked list. Then you can remove nodes with constant time complexity, provided you have a reference to the node that precedes the targeted node. You could also gain some time by aggregating neighboring senators of the same party into one such node, keeping a *count*. So for instance, if the input is "RDDDRRD", you could first convert that to this circular linked list:

```
    ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
    │ party: R  │   │ party: D  │   │ party: R  │   │ party: D  │
    │ num:   1  │   │ num:   3  │   │ val:   2  │   │ num: 1    │
┌─► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: ─┐  │
│   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └────────│──┘
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

With this data structure you can do the following:

- If the current node and the next node have the same party: merge them (sum their counts)
- Otherwise, if the next node has a count that is not more than the current node has senators that can take turns, remove that next node, and take note of how many senators in the current node took their turn to achieve that.
- Otherwise, reduce the count of the next node and make it the current.

If only one node remains, it has the party you want to return.

#### Solution Code

The above sketch of an algorithm results in this code:

```
class Solution(object):
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, party, num_senators):
            self.party = party
            self.num_senators = num_senators
            self.next = None

    def predictPartyVictory(self, senate):
        # Create a circular linked list
        sentinel = tail = Solution.Node("", 0)
        for span in re.findall(r"R+|D+", senate):  # Group same-party neighbors
            tail.next = Solution.Node(span[0], len(span))
            tail = tail.next
        curr = sentinel.next  # Remove sentinel
        tail.next = curr  # Make circular

        i = 0  # Number of senators in the current node that took a turn
        while curr.next is not curr:  # More than one party represented
            nxt = curr.next
            if nxt.party == curr.party:
                # Merge
                curr.num_senators += nxt.num_senators
                curr.next = nxt.next
            else:
                banned = min(curr.num_senators - i, nxt.num_senators)
                nxt.num_senators -= banned
                i += banned
                if not nxt.num_senators:  # Next group is empty
                    # Remove emptied node
                    curr.next = nxt.next
                if i == curr.num_senators:  # All in current node did their turn
                    i = 0
                    curr = curr.next  # Continue with next group of senators
        return "Radiant" if curr.party == "R" else "Dire"
```

Comment: Great diagram. Did you produce it manually or via some program?

Comment: Manually, but I have keyboard keys mapped to these box drawing characters.

Comment: Hi, I have been now looking into linked lists, but can you please explain to me what this section of your code does? ```for span in re.findall(r"R+|D+", senate):   
 # Group same-party neighbors
            tail.next = Solution.Node(span[0], len(span))
            tail = tail.next
        curr = sentinel.next  # Remove sentinel
        tail.next = curr  # Make circular ```

Comment: Specifically what does ```for span in re.findall(r"R+|D+", senate): ``` do, where is the "re" coming from?

Comment: `re` is the regular expression module. That regex is used to get substrings of all the same letters. You can see what it does if you add some print calls.